# Ошибка Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Перед открытием сайта появляется ошибка. http://www.gruzchiki-sofrino.ru/
Сайт экспортировался через Adobe Muse. Ошибка появляется только в Хроме 64 версии.
У кого есть идеи, как избавиться от нее?

Comment: Потрудитесь хотя-бы текст ошибки вынести в вопрос - не у всех есть хром-64! Минусую

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2452198

Comment: RaZik, помогло, спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `museutils.js` найдите строку `j = c.rules;` и замените её на `j = c.Rules;`

[Источник](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2452198)